# Getting Path is not canonical error while doing Functional Test Using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, robotframework, testcase

I am trying to write Robot Framework test for File Upload. I'm using the below Keyword to perform the function.

```
Choose File    ${UPLOAD_FILE_HIDDEN_INPUT}    ${UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}
```

where

```
${UPLOAD_FILE_HIDDEN_INPUT}    xpath=//input[@type="file"]
```

and `${UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}` is the Path location where I am trying to place the File that needs to be uploaded.

My testcase is in below directory

```
C:\Dev\Application\tests\functional\Robot\TestSuite\TestCase
```

I am placing the file which needs to be uploaded in below directory

```
C:\Dev\Application\tests\functional\Robot\Images\File1.jpg
```

I am declaring the variable `${UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}` in the variable section of the test case. In order to get to the File Location, I need to go back one Folder

```
C:\Dev\Application\tests\functional\Robot\
```

and then proceed to images Folder

```
C:\Dev\Application\tests\functional\Robot\Images
```

In-order to perform this, I am using below value to the variable

```
${UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}    ${CURDIR}\\..\\Images\\File1.jpg
```

But I am getting the below error

```
path is not canonical: C:\\Dev\\ClaimLogUI\\tests\\functional\\Robot\\TestSuite\\..\\Chrysanthemum.jpg\n  (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.86)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

I used similar kind of Folder notation as value to other files in some other scenario and it was working fine. I am not sure where I am going wrong in order to locate File1.jpg. I am using Chrome Browser to perform this test. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can use keyword **Normalize Path** from library OperatingSystem to make your path as a canonical

`${NORMAL_PATH_UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}    Normalize Path  ${UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}`

Then you can use this code without error

`Choose File    ${UPLOAD_FILE_HIDDEN_INPUT}    ${NORMAL_PATH_UPLOAD_FILE_NAME}`

(You can read this for futher information http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html)

Answer (score 1):

${CURDIR} is path to the directory where the test data file is located.

You should use ${EXECDIR} which is absolute path to the directory where test execution was started from.